# input prompt in a print statement python

Tags: python, input, printing

in the following example

```
print ("How old are you?" , input("please input"))
```

when executing it, why is it that it asks for input propmpt before printing "How old are you?"?
What is the order of execution of sections of print statement?

Comment: as a general rule, it is not a good habit to use expressions with side-effect (like `input()`), or expressions whose values depends on the order of evaluation, inside other expressions (like print).

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you pass to the `print()` function has to be executed *first*. How else would Python know what to pass to the `print()` function?

Generally speaking, in order for Python to call a function, you need to first determine what values you are passing into that function. See the [Calls expression documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> All argument expressions are evaluated before the call is attempted.

Calling `print()` you are passing in a string (`"How old are you?"`), and the *result* of calling `input("please input")`. Python has to execute those sub-expressions first before it can call `print()`.

In this specific case, just use `How old are you?` as the `input()` prompt:

```
age = input("How old are you? ")
```

and don't bother with `print()`.

If you did want to print `How old are you?` on a separate line first, call `print()` with *just* that string, then on a separate line, call `input()`:

```
print("How old are you?")
age = input("please input")
```

Note that `input()` returns whatever string the user entered, you want to store that somewhere. In my examples, `age` is that 'somewhere'.

Comment: but while executing the (print()) function, it passes ("How old are you?") first right? so isnt that supposed to print first?

Comment: @user2524557: No, you are passing two arguments to `print()`. They *both* need to be evaluated before calling `print()`.

Comment: @user2524557 what you are looking for is called [Lazy evaluation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_evaluation). very few languages has this feature.